# Is it possible to get whole nested object from a document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I have a document like this:

```json
{
  "_index": "bank-accounts",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 4,
  "_seq_no": 3,
  "_primary_term": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "id": 1,
    "balance": 140,
    "transactions": [
      {
        "id": "42f52474-a49b-4707-86e4-e983efb4ab31",
        "type": "Deposit",
        "amount": 100
      },
      {
        "id": "3f8396a3-d747-4a4c-8926-cdcedea6b5c3",
        "type": "Deposit",
        "amount": 50
      },
      {
        "id": "5693585d-6356-4d1a-8d7b-cac5d0dab39f",
        "type": "Withdraw",
        "amount": 10
      }
    ],
    "accountCreatedAt": 1614029062764
  }
}
```

I do want to return only the `transactions` array in a query.

How would I do this within Elasticsearch? Is this even possible? I've achieved a result using `fields[ "transactions.*" ]`, but it returns each of the fields in separate arrays:

```json
{
    ...
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "bank-accounts",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "transactions.id": [
            "42f52474-a49b-4707-86e4-e983efb4ab31",
            "3f8396a3-d747-4a4c-8926-cdcedea6b5c3",
            "5693585d-6356-4d1a-8d7b-cac5d0dab39f"
          ],
          "transactions.amount": [
            100,
            50,
            10
          ],
          "transactions.type": [
            "Deposit",
            "Deposit",
            "Withdraw"
          ],
          ...
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I mean, I could very well be using this, but I want something more simple to handle. I expect to get something like this:

****I have to use the document id in my search***

```json
{
    ...
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "bank-accounts",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3,
        "transactions": [
          {
            "id": "42f52474-a49b-4707-86e4-e983efb4ab31",
            "type": "Deposit",
            "amount": 100
          },
          {
            "id": "3f8396a3-d747-4a4c-8926-cdcedea6b5c3",
            "type": "Deposit",
            "amount": 50
          },
          {
            "id": "5693585d-6356-4d1a-8d7b-cac5d0dab39f",
            "type": "Withdraw",
            "amount": 10
          },
          ....
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to return the `transactions` array (as you have not mentioned any query condition, on which you need to search), you can achieve that using [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.11/search-fields.html#source-filtering).

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "transactions": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "balance": 140,
  "transactions": [
    {
      "id": "42f52474-a49b-4707-86e4-e983efb4ab31",
      "type": "Deposit",
      "amount": 100
    },
    {
      "id": "3f8396a3-d747-4a4c-8926-cdcedea6b5c3",
      "type": "Deposit",
      "amount": 50
    },
    {
      "id": "5693585d-6356-4d1a-8d7b-cac5d0dab39f",
      "type": "Withdraw",
      "amount": 10
    }
  ],
  "accountCreatedAt": 1614029062764
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "_source": [
    "transactions.*"
  ]
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66324257",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "transactions": [
            {
              "amount": 100,
              "id": "42f52474-a49b-4707-86e4-e983efb4ab31",
              "type": "Deposit"
            },
            {
              "amount": 50,
              "id": "3f8396a3-d747-4a4c-8926-cdcedea6b5c3",
              "type": "Deposit"
            },
            {
              "amount": 10,
              "id": "5693585d-6356-4d1a-8d7b-cac5d0dab39f",
              "type": "Withdraw"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Matheus Cirillo please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue?

Comment: . . .Perfect, it solved my issue. Just a little adaptation, since I had to query using the document id. . . `{"query":{"match":{"id":1}},"_source":["transactions.*"]}` did the job